# Plotting a curve on the mesh surface along only a determined axis

Tags: python, mesh, surf

I'm very new in Python and trying to plot a single curve on a surface.

Here is where I came so far and plotted a surface in s domain:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cmath

x = np.linspace(-400, 0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fc=50
wc=2*np.pi*fc

s = X + Y*1j
Z= abs(1/(1+s/wc))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.plot(X, Y, Z)
plt.ylabel('Im')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I now need to plot the curve for X = 0 in different color which means the curve on the same surface along the imaginary axis. surf = ax.plot_surface(0, Y, Z) did not work. Does anybody have experience with such plot?

Comment: You might have to figure out the intersection of your surface and the plane x=0.

Comment: Can you help me with this:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant you wanted to plot y=0 instead of x=0 (since x=0 would be pretty boring).

Since you want to plot a single slice of your data, you can't use the meshgrid format (or if you can, it would require some weird indexing that I don't want to figure out).

Here's how I would plot the y=0 slice:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cmath

x = np.linspace(-400, 0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fc=50
wc=2*np.pi*fc

s = X + Y*1j
Z= abs(1/(1+s/wc))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

# create data for y=0
z = abs(1/(1+x/wc))
ax.plot(x,np.zeros(np.shape(x)),z)

plt.ylabel('Im')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but I need for x = 0 which will show the low pass filter curve for steady state. Can you also add that to your answer? I tried to modify but didnt work

Comment: Is it z = abs(1/(1+y*1j/wc))   
ax.plot(np.zeros(np.shape(x)),y,z,'r')

Comment: Yes, that will get what you want. Note that in this case, your x and y have the same length, but it would be best to use `ax.plot(np.zeros(np.shape(y)),y,z,'r')`

Comment: thanx a lot mate!